# Not able to move javascript from index.html into external file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, google-chrome

I am working on a simple tensorflow.js project, and while I can run everything without errors if I put the js code right within the index.html file, if I try and reference an external js file, I get an error (this is in Chrome -- though I also get an error in Firefox):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Playing with TensorFlow.js</title>
  <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.12.5"> </script>
  <!-- Place your code in the script tag below. You can also use an external .js file -->
  <script type = "text/javascript" src = "../server/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

And the external JS file being referenced contains this code:

```
// Define a model for linear regression.
const model = tf.sequential();
model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 1, inputShape: [1] }));

// Prepare the model for training: Specify the loss and the optimizer.
model.compile({ loss: 'meanSquaredError', optimizer: 'sgd' });

// Generate some synthetic data for training.
const xs = tf.tensor2d([1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 1]);
const ys = tf.tensor2d([1, 3, 5, 7], [4, 1]);

// Train the model using the data.
model.fit(xs, ys, { epochs: 10 }).then(() => {
  // Use the model to do inference on a data point the model hasn't seen before:
  // Open the browser devtools to see the output
  model.predict(tf.tensor2d([5], [1, 1])).print();
});
```

Does the above code look correct? Is this just a Chrome security default? Is there a way around this?

By the way, this is the error:

> GET http://localhost:4800/server/app.js 404 (Not Found) localhost/:1
>
> Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:4800/server/app.js'
>   because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME
>   type checking is enabled.

Comment: do you see anything show up in your error console? Otherwise try adding in console.log statements randomly throughout the file to see if you can view them.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Added the error above.

Comment: It seems to be working for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/j1zpjpyr79. Was able to get it to work with a similar folder structure like you. Only thing different is how I access the `js` file `<script type="text/javascript" src="./src/index.js"></script>`

Make sure the path to the file is correct.

Comment: The message about the security check is just a result of the 404 error. The javascript file does not exist at the url http://localhost:4800/server/app.js - You should make sure it is really actually there and the name is spelt correctly (also lower/uppercase)

Comment: I guess, based on the error, this also begs the question: is there a way to disable strict MIME type checking?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds silly but is there a spelling mistake in the file name? The browser cant find the file. Is the file definitely in the "server" folder? Perhaps, try placing the .js file in the root folder and just having the Javascript file name without any destination. From the looks of it, this will be some easy but silly mistake.

Comment: I use VSC to help me find the file, using intellsense, and I've triple-checked it, it's right where it says it is.

Comment: Also, it's not clear to me that the error message would be what it is (see above) if the file merely couldn't be found. Surely if that's the case, that would be the error message.

Comment: Ah, I found the fix. So I think the issue was that because I'm using express, it's only looking for files pertaining to index.html in the "static" folder. So I moved the app.js file in there, made the appropriate update to the location in index.html, and, voila, it worked. :)

Comment: The error message is 404, which means it cant find the file. Make sure the server folder is in the root of your project because knowing Visual Studio your index file is actually in a View folder, not in the root of the project